# Values in a HashMap are being overriden everytime I put a key value in the HashMap

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have this flink program below:

```
object WindowedWordCount {
    class MyCoMap extends RichCoMapFunction[String, String, String] {

      private var usersMap: MapState[String, String] = _

      override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
          usersMap = getRuntimeContext.getState(
          //Error here
          new MapStateDescriptor[String, String]("usersMap", TypeInformation[String], TypeInformation[String)
      )}

      override def map1(value: String): String = {
        //Grab userId and timeStampOfUserId here
        usersMap.put(userId,timeStampOfUserId)
        println(usersMap)
        "Adding user from event stream to global map: " + timeStampOfUserId
      }

      override def map2(value: String): String = {
          //Do something with the second stream
      }
    }
}
```

The problem I have in the above code is that in the `map1` function inside of the `MyCoMap` class when I add a `key-value` to my `users HashMap` defined globally, for some reason every `key-value` I add, it is overriding the previous value. So my map always contains 1 `key-value` in it...

For example if it adds `users.put("user1", "abc")` the map will contain `{"user1"="abc"}` then puts another `key-value` `users.put("user2", "abc")` the map will becomes `{"test2"="abc"}` instead of `{"test1"="abc", "test2"="abc"}`.

**EDIT:**

Yes I would like to join on userId. Stream1 is coming in at 1 message per second while stream2 is coming in at 1 message per 6 seconds. I want to add the userId from stream1 into a `MapState` (in the `map1` function) and then in the `map2` function I want to check if the `userID` from stream2 is present in the `MapSate`.

I have a lack of knowledge in this field but when you say keyed state I am assuming all the keys that are the same will be processed on the same node correct and that each node gets it’s own `MapState` object? Since my main concern is that when I am joining the userId from stream2 I want to make sure I have all the userId’s from stream1 collected and that they are on the same node when lookup in the `MapState` occurs in map2 function.

Comment: You shouldn't be using mutable data structures. Especially global ones. Especially, unsynchronized. And DEFINITELY not with flink, or spark or other distributed framework like that.

Comment: @Dima I have added an edit to my question. Can you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your requirements right, you want to join two streams on a `user`.

This can be done by keying both streams on the `user` field:

```
val stream1: DataStream[(String, String)] = ??? // first field is user
val stream2: DataStream[(String, String)] = ??? // first field is user

val connected: DataStream[X] = stream1
  .connect(stream2) // connect both streams
  .keyBy(_._1, _._1) // key both streams on first field
  .map(new YourCoMapFunction())
```

The `CoMapFunction` should use [Keyed State](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/state.html#using-managed-keyed-state), i.e., state that is keyed on the same attribute as you `keyBy` on (user in your case). So keyed state is essentially a sharded, distributed `HashMap`. Note that keyed state can only be locally accessed. When working with state you have to make sure that you remove all state that you do not need anymore. Otherwise, your state might grow too large at some point.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Can you please take a look at my edit really quick in my question? I had some doubts.

Comment: Yes, `keyBy` partitions by key, i.e., all records with the same key are processed by the same operator. Also, you might not need a `MapState`, because the state is already partitioned by key. If you only need one value per user, you should go with `ValueState`. Each user will have its own `ValueState`.